# How to do a proper shutdown of worker service in this example

Tags: c#, .net-core, lifecycle, worker-service

I have this workerservice which in essence is a TCP socket server.

This is my main where i select to set up the service depending on the OS.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log log = new();
            Socket socket = new SocketConnection().getSocket();
            try
            {
                DataStorage.Instance.osPlatform = RuntimeInformation.OSDescription;
                if (DataStorage.Instance.osPlatform.Contains("Win"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WinOS");
                    CreateHostBuilderWin(args).Build().Run();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("MacOS");
                    CreateHostBuilderMac(args).Build().Run();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.write("Could not start SDS. ", ex);
            }
            
            log.write("Program is reached on shutdown", null);
        }

        public static void configureServices(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilderWin(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseWindowsService()
           .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
           {
               services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
           });

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilderMac(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            //Hvorfor dette?
            .ConfigureServices(configureServices);
    }
```

This is the Worker, where i start the clientServer with a socket as parameter. And here is the problem.

I cant seem to shutdown the service properly. I initialize and instantiate a Socket, and i want to dispose of it when the service is stopped or crashes.

The disposal takes plase in the EndSDS Class

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SDS.BusinessLogic;
using SDS.Singleton;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SDS.Service.Tools;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SDS

{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        Log log = new();
        ClientServer clientServer;
        SocketConnection socket = new();
        Socket listener;
        EndSDS endSDS;
        private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

        public Worker(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
        {
            _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
                try{
                    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // hvis pludseligt det går galt med initialiseringen så skal SDS stoppe
                            // ved næste gennemløb
                            if (DataStorage.Instance.sdsInitialized)
                            {
                                log.write("startasync is reached", null);
                                listener = socket.getSocket();
                                log.write("Socket: " + listener.AddressFamily + " " + listener.RemoteEndPoint, null);
                                await clientServer.start(listener);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                log.write("Sds not initialized properly", null);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            log.write("Could not create Socket for server", ex);
                        }
                    }

                }
                finally
                {
                    log.write("Finally reached", null);
                    _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
                }
                
            }
  

            //log.write("Worker is reached on shutdown", null);
        

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            log.write("StartAsync is reached on startup", null);

            clientServer = new();
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            log.write("StopAsync is reached on shutdown", null);
            endSDS = new EndSDS();
            endSDS.start(listener);
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
       /* public override void Dispose()
        {
            log.write("Dispose is reached on shutdown", null);
            endSDS.start(listener);
            base.Dispose();
        }*/
    }
}
```

Here is the EndSDS class.

```
using SDS.Controllers;
using SDS.Singleton;
using SDS.Service.Tools;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;

namespace SDS.BusinessLogic
{
    internal class EndSDS
    {
        private FilesController files = new();
        private Log log = new();
        internal EndSDS()
        {

        }

        internal void start(Socket socket)
        {
            log.write("socket closing", null);
            if (socket != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    socket.Close();
                    socket.Dispose();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.write("logclose exception. ", ex);
                };
                log.write("Socket Disposed", null);
            }
            log.write("SDS ended. ", null);
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is.

1. I start the service, and it starts properly because i can connect to it and talk to it. I can also see the "StartAsync is reached on startup" in the log
2. I stop the service, and StopAsync is not being run. Nothing happens. The log are not written to the logs.
3. I start the service, and it does not start the clientServer, as the port is not closed and i get a message saying that in the log.
4. I stop the service, and StopAsync runs, and everyting is ok.
5. rince and repeat.

Can anybody help me ?, i have no idea what the problem is.

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: how do you stop the service?

Comment: Also, are your logs flushing? Though, i am more curious about why you a creating an object in a stop method, and then calling start to close a socket...

Comment: I stop the service with sc.exe stop ServiceName

Comment: Im just reusing some code because im trying my way forward. :) Im trying to find the spot that activates when i type sc.exe stop ServiceName. What do you mean by "logs flushing". Im a total newb at services, and this is for an exam project, so im just learning. Im using my own logs Class, as this service has to run on both mac and win, and i was afraid that the buildt in log system only worked on win.